# Is there a special way to load an image from a phone's camera into img for Android Firefox

Tags: image, file, firefox, input, upload

I am trying to load an image from a phone's camera into an image tag. It works great everywhere except Firefox on Android. Firefox version is 83.1.0  Below is the simple JavaScript and HTML that produces the issue. All I want to do is take a picture using the camera and load it into the img tag to display. Works great in Chrome and even Samsung's dopey internet browser. Just not in Firefox. The image does not display.
What am I doing wrong?

```
window.onload = function() {
let imgInput = document.querySelector('#imageInput');
   
   imgInput.addEventListener('change',function(event) {
      var files = this.files;
      var fr = new FileReader();
   
      fr.onload = function () {
         document.getElementById('image').src = fr.result;
      }

      fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
   });
};

...

<input id="imageInput" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<img id="image" style="height: 300px; width: auto;"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be two potential problems:

- Your Firefox for Android version is outdated. There is a issue report that shows that image capture via `<input type="file">` might be broken in older versions: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/8711
- The usage of a data: URL instead of blob: URL. Firefox for Android seems to have a pretty low limit on the data: URL length. A high resolution image might be too large. [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) creates a blob URL instead.

I successfully tested the following implementation on Firefox for Android Nightly:

```
<input type=file accept="image/*" id="imageInput">
<img id="image">
<script>
var imgInput = document.querySelector("#imageInput");
imgInput.addEventListener('change',function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  document.getElementById('image').src = url;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to SO :) I'm a bit confused about your code because you mention "loading an image from the camera" but you are also loading a file.

**Updated answer: use WebRTC**

As @evilpie mentioned, `ImageCapture` is currently not supported in Firefox. However, MDN has another nice article about [using WebRTC to take still pictures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos).

Here's the `takepicture` function as depicted in the article. It uses a [video element](https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/blob/7e79e8fb43b20c59f5d78eb8fc20316db9fb3ac7/s/webrtc-capturestill/capture.js#L23-L54) to receive the WebRTC stream, then renders the content of that element in a Canvas. The content is then converted to a data URL for showing in another component.

```js
  function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (width && height) {
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    } else {
      clearphoto();
    }
  }
```

**Old answer (does not work: `ImageCapture` is not supported in Firefox)**

The MDN Website has a [nice example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/takePhoto) exactly for loading an image from the camera. The example works across all the browsers (a demo is [available here](https://simpl.info/imagecapture/)):

```js
var takePhotoButton = document.querySelector('button#takePhoto');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

takePhotoButton.onclick = takePhoto;

function takePhoto() {
  imageCapture.takePhoto().then(function(blob) {
    console.log('Took photo:', blob);
    img.classList.remove('hidden');
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('takePhoto() error: ', error);
  });
}
```

The full JS code for the demo is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/gh-pages/imagecapture/js/main.js).

Comment: ImageCapture is not supported in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88817

Comment: Sorry. I meant https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888177